# Tiny cursor after logout

Tags: gnome, gdm, cursor

[image: cursor]

I am using GNOME with a 4k monitor and 200% scaling and everything seems to be working fine, but after logging out and logging back in, cursor scaling seems to reset to 100%. I am attaching the photo since taking a screenshot fixes cursor scaling back to normal. The cursor also goes back to normal if I change the display scaling to 100% and then back to 200%.

Comment: Looks like a bug with Gnome. Please post it here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks, reported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Gnome Extension, not the Gnome itself.

The extension name is "Soft brightness" and it seems to be fixed now.